# Failed to store into mailbox 'INBOX': Internal error occurred

Tags: dovecot

I have a problem that I don't know what's going on. I have an account that in the inbox has more than 100000 emails, I performed the re-indexing of the account, I made the copy of the emails and I already moved to another folder I deleted all the emails from the inbox and even so the emails no longer reach the inbox. my dovecot is configured dbox is there any email limit per folder? the log doesn't show me anything. I'll post the log here for you to take a look at.

```
2022-04-28T12:11:15.985639620Z Apr 28 12:11:15 lmtp(publicacoes@atitudejur.com.br): Error: rename(/srv/dovecot2/mail/DOMINIO.com.br/publicacoes/storage/.temp.1651147875.P99844Q1M867714.97c55cacfb0a, /srv/dovecot2/mail/DOMINIO.com.br/publicacoes/storage/m.141313) failed: No space left on device
2022-04-28T12:11:15.986651832Z Apr 28 12:11:15 lmtp(EMAIL): Error: uOb6LmOEamIEhgEA5dpidw: sieve: msgid=unspecified: failed to store into mailbox 'INBOX': Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2022-04-28 12:11:15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it says "No space left on device". Is your device full ?
Check also the used inodes (`df -i`) to make sure they are not depleted.